# On the Tikz Shape var resistor IEC

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits

In the Tikz manual there is an example to generate the figure below:
[image]
I tried to see if the code works after applying @Zarco comment to add definition for shape example style:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
shape example/.style= {color = black!30,
draw,
fill = yellow!30,
line width = .5cm,
inner xsep = 2.5cm,
inner ysep = 0.5cm}
}
\node[name=s,shape=var resistor IEC,shape example,minimum 
width=7cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\foreach \anchor/\placement in
{center/above, 30/above right,
north/above, south/below, east/left, west/right,
north east/above, south east/below, south west/below, north west/above,
input/left,output/right}
\draw[shift=(s.\anchor)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But got an error:
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `center' (in 'center').
Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: You need add definition for *shape example* style. It is described in manula, Section 71, page 785: `\tikzset{shape example/.style= {color = black!30, draw, fill = yellow!30,
line width = .5cm, inner xsep = 2.5cm, inner ysep = 0.5cm}}`.

Comment: ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `center' (in 'center'). still getting error @Zarko

Comment: Please first complete  this example as I suggest you in previous comment that people can test your MWE. BTW,  I can't confirm your claim.

Comment: Zarko I edited my question including your comment about shape example. We get error still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for the comment ...

With code copied from your question, I can confirm that happens some error (in my case `Unknown function` right' (in 'right'). If I construct your MWE from scratch with copying code fragments from Ti*k*Z $ PGF Manual, version 3.1.9a:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{
shape example/.style = {color=black!30,
                        draw,
                        fill = yellow!30,
                        line width = .5cm,
                        inner xsep = 2.5cm,
                        inner ysep = 0.5cm}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s,shape=var resistor IEC, shape example,
      minimum width=7cm, minimum height=1cm] {};
\foreach \anchor/\placement in {
    center/above,       30/above,
    north/above,        south/below, 
    east/left,          west/right,
    north east/above,   south east/below, 
    south west/below,   north west/above,
    input/left,         output/right}
\draw[shift=(s.\anchor)] 
    plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)} node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It compile fine: without any errors, warnings or bad boxes:

[image]

however, the result is not the same as in manula (background is reduced to a line).

It seems, that in your copy of code might be hidden some invisible character which cause error. You may report your finding to package maintainers.